# sql server 2000 backup with agent

Tags: sql-server-2000, backup

I have this script to backup my sql server 2000 database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [CRM] TO DISK = N'd:\CRM_BACKUP\crm.bak'  
WITH NOINIT, NOUNLOAD, NAME = N'GUY_CRM_BACKUP', NOSKIP, STATS = 10, NOFORMAT
```

I want the backup to be for several days.

I thought about giving the name of the backup the day of the month

e.g. `crm01.bak`, `crm02.bak`.... crm30 or `crm31.bak`.

How can I do that please?

TIA

Guy

Answer (score 0):

You can set `RETAINDAYS` to the number of days you wish to keep that backup.  Since you are using `NOSKIP` (and `NOFORMAT`), SQL Server will not overwrite that backup until it has expired.  At that point, you could also institute a naming standard like you are mentioning, or set a maintenance plan to erase backups older than a certain age.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you show me how to make it backup with incremental filenames like I mentioned?

Comment: You would probably setup a job to do this.  I might recommend starting by creating a maintenance plan, which includes a wizard that walks you through some of these tasks (including customization like you're asking about).  You can read a [great primer by Brad McGahee](https://www.red-gate.com/community/books/sql-server-maintenance-plans).